# jQuery POST Upon Button Click not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with a function that is called when a button is clicked.

**Javascript :**

```
function sendData(){
     $.post("send.php",
         {
          type: "A",
          val: "answer"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert(data);
        });
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="testButton" onclick="sendData();">click</div>
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value
    }
?>
```

I post the data to the php page and expect to receive the data back. The javascript should alert the data upon a successful call.

When the button is clicked, nothing happens.

Please can someone see if there is anything wrong with the code.

Comment: check your console..there is any error?

Comment: Check the network tab of the developer tools in your browser. Is the request sent to the server? What is in the response and especially in the response header?

Comment: @eztam Yes the request is sent and 0.62kb are received back.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya There are no errors when the page loads or on button click

Comment: @AlexAndrei The type and val I believe form the data parameter. Maybe I have got confused..

Comment: Can you try $.ajax? because it has error handler function also

Comment: @user2216919 Does the response body contain the right data and is the response status = 200 ?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Due to network restrictions, the response comes back as 405 Not Allowed. Body is 405 Not Allowed. I used a VPN to bypass restrictions, still not working, but I am unable to view the console that way.

Comment: are you getting access-control-allow-origin error?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya No, it is my school's SmoothWall, which blocks access to certain websites. The response-headers mention the smoothwall in the X-Cache and and Via attributes. I assume this may be the problem. Although it does still not work on VPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code return :

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

You have just to add semicolon `;` in the end after `echo $value`, should be :

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
         echo $value;
    } 
?>
```

**FULL CODE :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function sendData(){
             $.post("send.php",
                 {
                  type: "A",
                  val: "answer"
                },
                function(data,status){
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testButton" onclick="sendData();">click</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I added the semi-colon. Still not working. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Check your console, it should work, it's work localy on my machine

Comment: @user2216919 I've added full  code to the answer, you could check it.

Comment: It's weird. It isn't for me. My desktop network is blocking access to it. But even using mobile data on my phone to where it is hosted it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `send.php` in the same directory with html file? check the browser console for errors?

Comment: Yep, send.php is in the same directory. I tried your latest answer. I can see the request being made but still no alert box.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to think so. I'll see what I can do. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing a semi colon in the send.php file

```
<?php
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
     echo $value;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed that. However it still does not work

Comment: I tested your code (adding the semi colon) and it works on my side

Comment: On the desktop it doesn't work due to network restrictions and it's the same using mobile data.